# Can the absolute Galois group of a proper subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ be finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Given a proper subfield $F\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$, with $\bar{F}$ an algebraic closure of $F$, can the Galois group of $\bar{F}$ over $F$ be finite?

My first guess would be the answer is the Galois group can't be finite, but I'm not really sure how to approach thinking about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $Gal(\bar K,K)$ is finite, then it is of order at most $2$. This is the Artin-Schreier Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $F=\overline{\mathbb Q}\cap\mathbb R$; it is easy to see that $\overline F=\overline{\mathbb Q}$, since $F$ contains $\mathbb Q$ and is contained in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. On the other hand, we claim that $\overline{\mathbb Q}=F[i]$. Indeed, for any $z\in\overline{\mathbb Q}$, both
$$a=\frac{z+\overline z}2\text{ and }b=\frac{z-\overline z}{2i}$$
are real algebraic numbers, since $\overline z$ is algebraic, and $z=a+bi$. This implies that $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline F/F)\cong\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is finite.

In some sense, this is the only sort of example which may occur. A theorem of [Artin and Schreier](https://mathoverflow.net/a/8759/74600) from 1927 implies that, if $K$ is algebraically closed and $F\subset K$ has finite index, then $[K:F]\in\{1,2\}$ and in the second case $K$ is formed from $F$ by adjoining a square root of $-1$.